# EXE packer/EXE Compresser for application in C#/VB.net

Tags: c#

Is there any EXE packer/EXE Compresser available for application developed in C#/VB.net?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to compress your application binary? Or you want to compress files?

Comment: Exe packers compress executables transparently, so they are still executable - it's not the same as .zip.

Comment: Please take a look at my software .netshrink (exe-compression with LZMA, virtual DLL binding) you can ask me anything about it :)

Comment: try to use .netshrink, after compression my wpf app not run, just nothing happens when double click on .exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one: http://madebits.com/netz/index.php

Comment: Seems that the `netz` packer or how it was called is no longer supported /  available.

Comment: I would delete the answer, but it's accepted, so I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to merge multiple assemblies into a single file you can try [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en), it's available from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly use BoxedApp Packer for C #. With it you can pack all the exe quickly and efficiently. More information can find it here: http://boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/

Comment: I also advise it. powerful sdk.